# Открытие модального окна через ссылку

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Здравствуйте всем, вот вопрос - как сделать вывод модального окна по ссылкe .. например как в vk фотографии ?

Answer (score 1):

Что значит "вывод модального окна по ссылкe"? И что вам мешает использовать готовые плагины, например, [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)? Даже вот - [тут найдете обзор 15-ти аналогичных плагинов](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=1425).

**UPD**

Для каждого плагина есть свои способы подключения. На то и пишется инструкция к ним на офф.сайтах. Например, все тот же fancybox: [заходим на страничку мануала](http://fancybox.net/) Прокрутите в самый низ (последнее черное окошко с кодом.) Вот что мы видим:

```
/* HTML */
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="image_big_1.jpg"><img src="image_small_1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="image_big_2.jpg"><img src="image_small_2.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group2" href="image_big_3.jpg"><img src="image_small_3.jpg" alt=""/></a> 
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group2" href="image_big_4.jpg"><img src="image_small_4.jpg" alt=""/></a>

/* This will create two galleries */

$("a.grouped_elements").fancybox();
```

Не вооруженным взглядом можно заметить, что структура такова:
ссылка ведущая на оригинал фото, внутри миниатюрка этого фото. Остальное за вас делает скрипт - по нажатию на миниатюру, открывает в модальном окне оригинал.

Comment: Вот например  - http://vk.com/durov?z=photo1_283213319%2Fphotos1 - открывает окно , как сделать такое ?

Comment: Именно про это я и говорю. Что ж тут не понятного? Скачиваете плагин на ваш вкус, читаете на его сайте как подключить и вперед за орденами.

Comment: так вот в чем проблема, как сделать что бы по ссылке оно открывало именно ту фотографию ? ) может я мало подумал, обьясните пожалуйста

Comment: Спасибо , я посмотрю, если будут вопросы вы можете мне дать email,skype ? Доставать не буду , только по делу. 

P.S Нажатие на картинку и открытие - отлично, а вот что бы оно открывало по адресу. я ввожу например /photo/121 - открывает модальное окно с нужным фото.

Comment: Если вы уже решили взяться за это направление, то не мешало бы подучить JS и вслед за ним jQuery. Иначе, могу с уверенностью сказать, что вопросы у вас только начинаются, а когда закончаться - не известно.

P.S. Задавать вопросы мне (или не мне) можно и тут, для этого скайп не нужен.

Comment: я учу js , вы можете мне подсказать на счет 
' Нажатие на картинку и открытие - отлично, а вот что бы оно открывало по адресу. я ввожу например /photo/121 - открывает модальное окно с нужным фото.'

Comment: Я не вникал как все устроено вконтакте. Думаю, что способов реализации можно натйи несколько. Например, с помощью php отловить URI, вытащить по параметру из БД адрес нужной картинки и из того же php запустить js-скрипт.

    echo "<script>someFunc(someParam);<script>";

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам поможет это [jquery window plugin](http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/)